# PostgreSQL Log Rotation Size Reached File Limit

Tags: postgresql

I have configured the following settings in PostgreSQL 13 on Windows.

```
logging_collector = on  
log_rotation_size='100MB'
log_truncate_on_rotation = on    
log_filename ='postgresql-%Y-%m-%d.log'
```

I have configured PostgreSQL to create a daily log. Is it possible for PostgreSQL to create another file (with the configured file name) and rename the existing file by appending with a different file name when the file reaches its configured log_rotation_size?

Do I have to run some script or services on the background so that the program is able to monitor the data/logs folder and rename the file when the log file size reaches the limit?

Answer (score 0):

On Linux you would have PostgreSQL create a log with a simple name (such as postgresql.log) and then configure logrotate to manage the PostgreSQL log, rotating and deleting it as you require.

Information to support this (though not telling you *how* to do this) is in the [PostgreSQL docs section on log file maintenance](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/logfile-maintenance.html).

However, on Windows you (probably) won't have this option, so how the file is rotated is up to you, whether by a script or some other utility.

Answer (score 0):

Citing from the Postgres manual ... https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-logging.html

*log_filename (string)*

*When logging_collector is enabled, this parameter sets the file names of the created log files. The value is treated as a strftime pattern, so %-escapes can be used to specify time-varying file names.*

So if you set up your name to something like this, you shoudl have no conflict unless you reach 100MB of logs within one second, limit set in your config.

**postgresql-%Y-%m-%d_%H%M%S.log**

HTH, Z.